# Calculate mean value of the function

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals, average, mean-value-theorem

I need to calculate the average of $f(x)$ function.  $f(x)$ is defined in a $[0,\pi]$

The regular integral average or $0$ harmonic of fourier series does not work as the $f$ function has many extremum points, so integral calculation is not efficient.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_of_a_function

I tried the probabilistic method (as this function is defined in a $[0, \pi]$), that works not bad, but again not acceptable yet.

Is there any other way of function average calculation.

---

## EDIT:

So finally, after suggestions in comments,I would like suggestions to effectively compute, or (if that’s not possible at all) approximate closely, the following expression: $$\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\pi \sin(x)\sin(3x)\sin(5x)…\sin((2n+1)x) dx.$$

Comment: I don’t understand. Why is it “not acceptable yet”?

Comment: It requires a lot of calculations.  function itself is very complex and each value calculation requires many operations.

Comment: What IS the function?

Comment: It is not a single function, but the class of functions, for example $f_n(x)=\sin(x)\sin(3x)\sin(5x)... \sin(nx)$

Comment: So you want to find the mean like $\frac1n(f_1+f_2+…f_n)$?

Comment: The exact definition is here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_of_a_function

Comment: I have edited your post. Please review to see whether it is a correct interpretation  or not.

Comment: Actually I do not see any edit. Should I look at some specific location?

Comment: A natural approach is to reframe everything in terms of the complex Fourier basis $e_{k}(x)=e^{ikx}$ ($k$ an integer), which is orthonormal with respect to$$\langle{f,g}\rangle=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}f\bar{g},$$and to use the identity$$\sin(kx)=\frac{e^{ikx}-e^{-ikx}}{2i}.$$(That may not give a closed formula for the Fourier coefficients, but it reduces the evaluation to algebra.)

Comment: Thank you just accepted your changes.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang thank you, let me see if this will become to something useful.